# How can I increase the CPUs and Memory available to Docker in Linux?

Tags: linux, docker, amazon-ec2

When I run docker info in my Amazon Linux AMI EC2 instance I get:

```
Operating System: Amazon Linux AMI 2017.09
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 993.4MiB
```

How can I increase the number of CPUs and memory available to docker? With only 1 CPU my docker container is exiting immediately with an exit code of 137 (which I understand means out of memory).

I know how to change these setting on my Mac Docker instance, but not on the Linux instance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my problem was simply that the Amazon t2.micro instance I was using simply didn't have the necessary cpus/memory available.

Upgraded to t2.medium which has 2CPUs and 4GB of memory and that fixed it.